# C# - Deserializing Of Object Result and Map it to List From Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net, httpclient

Good day,

I'm trying to deserialize a list in my api but the problem, the api has an object.

My API result looks like this:

```
{
    result:[
    {
        "name": "Jessica"
    },
    {
        "name": "May"
    },
    {
        "name": "Joseph"
    }]
}
```

This is my code to deserialize it which it fails because I'm not getting a list from api because of the `result`.

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();

var task = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://something.com/api/whatever");

return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Whatever>>(task);
```

My `Whatever.cs` looks like this

```
public class Whatever {
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Is there a way like I remove the result  to be able to deserialize it as a list or is there any option provided by Newtonsoft.JSON to trim the `result` and make it a list instead of an object?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your Json is not a list though, its an object with a single property called "result" that is a list.  So make your class represent that and you will be golden

Comment: The best option is to actually create the extra class, it is clearer, and less room for errors all around. However, if you absolutely don't want that class you can ask Json.Net for help. Try this: `JObject.Parse(task)["result"].ToObject<List<Whatever>>()`

Comment: yes @maccettura I know. It's not a list. that's why I'm getting an error in deserializing because of the `result`

Comment: @jsonGPPD ok so do what I said to fix it and you are fine.

Comment: You can create a wrapper class with a result member such as public List<Whatever> result. Or try what @LasseVågsætherKarlsen suggests.

Comment: Thank you so much @LasseVågsætherKarlsen it works.. Please put it on the answer box so I can mark it as the answer. To help others as well :)

Comment: @jsonGPPD as Lasse already warned, its not a good idea to do this.  Your class structure should match your JSON 100%.  Your code becomes hard to read and hard to debug when you do hacky stuff like this

Comment: No, sorry, I'm not going to do that. The right way is still to create that class, so I'm not going to post an answer detailing how to do it in the hackish way instead.

Answer (score 3):

Your class should be like this.

```
public class Result
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Result> result { get; set; }
}
```

and you can serialize this json:

```
{
    result: [{
        'name': 'Jessica'
    },
    {
        'name': 'May'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Joseph'
    }]
}
```

Like this:

```
var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
```

for class creation you can use [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)